# Setup MongoDB on Windows Server 2008

Tags: mongodb, windows-server-2008

I'm new to mongoDB and like it so far, I work local for my dev where I have mongo running as service on Win7. I have it allso running as a service on my VPS on Win server 2008. When I am on the server it works fine but I don't know hos to set it up so I can acces it from outside of the server? Can't find any good documentation on that. Also, I'm having hard time to do backup/restore on the server from my local computer since I can't see it from outside of the server.

I would like to have more information also on the master/slave and hos to set this up properly.

When I run netstat -anb I get

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
 [mongod.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:27017        127.0.0.1:62990        ESTABLISHED
 [mongod.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:28017        0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

That's all I have for mongod.exe

[Edit]

I tried to reinstall with --bind_ip xxx.x.x.xx and now the xxx.x.x.xx:27017 works but only on the remote server, if I try to access from anywhere it fails.

Also, I turned off the firewall and it does not change anything.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your problem is firewall related. Have you tried portscanning with nmap or telneting to those ports from the remote machine?

Comment: Thanks again Justin for the help! I get a could not open connection to the host on port 27017 : connection failde...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think I found how to achieve it. First of all, allow the port 27017 on your firewall. Then I installed Mongo as a service using a configuration file. I created the mongos.conf like this:

```
dbpath = d:\mongo\data
logpath = d:\mongo\logs
noauth = true # use 'true' for options that don't take an argument
```

I saved it under: d:\mongo\mongos.conf

Then I did this in the command line:

```
mongod --config d:\mongo\mongos.conf --reinstall
```

The key is to make sure there is no bind_ip config key in your configuration file. So it will allow mongo to be binded to any ip. You should then be able to go to

http://localhost:27017 and see the following message:

```
You are trying to access MongoDB on the native driver port. For http diagnostic access, add 1000 to the port number
```

And you should also be able to go to:

http://192.168.x.x:27017 (your ip) and you should see the same output.

Answer (score 7):

In the **mongod.cfg** (at C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin), just update:

```
# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
#  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

Then restart the MongoDB Server service

let the mongo db bing to 0.0.0.0 i.e. all interfaces and not only 127.0.0.1.
Then it will allow connections to all interfaces.

Answer (score 4):

Try running this command from an admin DOS prompt to open external access to the default MongoDB port 27017:

```
C:\> netsh.exe advfirewall firewall add rule name="MongoDB (port 27017)"
        dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=27017
```

Comment: even if i turned off the firewall? is it the same than adding the exception with the firewall window?

Comment: it tells me that netsh.exe is not a valid Win32 application

Comment: Yes, running netsh is the same as opening a port through the GUI.  Maybe there's something else blocking port 27017, a router?  Or maybe you local machine blocking outbound connections?

Comment: It's not local machine since we try on an other server and it works, seems like the hosting service is blocking it. I opened a support ticket but did not get any reply yet, anyway thaks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you can't access it remotely it sounds like a firewall issue. By default mongod listens on port 27017. Is that port accessible from the machine you are trying to connect from? This sounds like more or a firewall issue than an issue with mongod. Can you edit your question to provice the command line the mongo service runs as.

A good source for information on replica sets in [this article](http://www.snailinaturtleneck.com/blog/2010/08/03/part-3-replica-sets-in-the-wild/) on [Kristina Chodorow's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4243/kristina) blog.

Comment: Hi Justin, I already have port 27017 exception for the windows firewall, with TCP protocol. On localhost:27017 on the server I can see that it works but not from the outside. Mongo run as service using Mongo DB. It works fine when staying on the local server but I can't access it from the outside.

Comment: Is there a hardware firewall between your mongo server and the machine you are trying to access it from? Run nmap from the machine you are trying to remotely connect to your server from and see if the port is filtered. Also, what is the full command line that mongo is running with? Are you using --bind_ip? Finallyuse netstat to ensure that mongo is listening on on 0.0.0.0:27017

Comment: I run mongod.exe as a service like in this post : http://www.deltasdevelopers.com/post/Running-MongoDB-as-a-Windows-Service.aspx without the --bind_ip, do you think it could be why it's not working? When I run netstat I get nothing on port 27017.

Comment: That article is a bit out of date. Look at the one I wrote. http://www.justaprogrammer.net/2010/09/30/mongodb-as-a-windows-service/.

Comment: about one year later and I'm facing the problem right now, my client wants to change for a share hosting so I need to access the DB from a different server, I updated the question with more info.

Answer (score 1):

For MongoDb 4.x I did the following things:

1. I edited firewall and enabled port 27017 access on host computer.
2. By default MongoDb is installed on `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin` in Windows and it contains a file called `mongod.cfg`.

   - I open my notepad++ editor in admin mode and edit the file.
   - Find the `bindIp: 127.0.0.1` and added host ip `bindIp: 127.0.0.1, 192.168.1.xxx`
3. Restart MongoDb service and you should be able to access it from another computer `192.168.1.xxx:27017`.

Answer (score 1):

**Install mongo and setup**

1. Install mongodb with windows service checked
2. Allow specific port in firewall: 27017
3. In the mongod.cfg (at C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin), just comment bindIp: 127.0.0.1 and add new line bindIp: 0.0.0.0:

```html
    # network interfaces
    net:
      port: 27017
    #  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
      bindIp: 0.0.0.0
```

Last two steps will allow you remote access

**create user**

1. Open cmd go to path of installation, for example C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin
2. in cmd type mongo
   C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.4\bin>mongo
3. then type use admin (admin is database)
   and at the end
4. db.createUser( { user: "adminName", pwd: "xxxxxx", roles: ["readWrite"] })
5. restart mongo service in services

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable Windows Firewall 27017 port for public & private.
2. exit current mongoDB, re-run mongod

some details can be refer to this article 
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-install-mongodb-windows-server/